# how to prevent ios universal link open the APP when user click a url in subdomain A page, and the url is linking to subdomain B

Tags: ios, apple-app-site-association

We added associated domains in our ios APP, like this:

```
<string>webcredentials:*.mywebsite.com</string>
<string>applinks:*.mywebsite.com</string>
```

We also uploaded apple-app-site-association file for all our subdomains. Like below:

```
{
   "applinks": {
      "apps": [],
      "details": [
         {
            "appID": "XXXXX.com.mywebsite.www",
            "paths": [
               "NOT /whatever",
               "some other paths here",
               "/"
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "webcredentials": {
      "apps": [
         "XXXXX.com.mywebsite.www"
      ]
   }
}
```

It works fine if user click a url on google page which links to [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com), it will open the APP.

But my problem is, if we have a subdomainA.mywebsite.com/test.html, like this:

```
<a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/">HOME</a>
```

If user click the link, it will also open the APP, this is NOT what i want.

So my question is, how can i disable universal link opening the APP if on subdomainA user clicks a url that links to subdomainB, and the url's path is registered in app site association file. Can ios know they are just subdomains so don't open the APP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We ended up asking Apple for help. As I expected, we cannot tell Apple/IOS not to launch APP between two subdomains with same universal links. The only way we can do is, if in subdomain B there is a url link to subdomain A, and this url is universal link, we have to add some special query or hash to the url, for example, url?within_subdomains=1, then in the AASA file, we add "NOT *within_subdomains=1",

Answer (score 3):

You can disable Universal links by blacklisting the paths in your AASA file.
Adding **NOT** before the path in your AASA file won't trigger app open for your url.

```
{
"applinks": {
    "apps": [ ],
    "details": [
        {
            "appID": "XXXXX.com.mywebsite.www",
            "paths": [ "http://www.mywebsite.com/", "NOT http://www.subdomainA.mywebsite.com/test.html"]
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the apple documentation for the same:
[Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)

Comment: I don't think in paths we can specify protocol and domain? But thanks for your answer, i will try it no matter what.

Comment: We can specify url or a certain path with wildcard characters in "paths". I have done same for my applications. Follow the apple documentation for the same.

Comment: i think if put `NOT http://subdomainA.mywebsite.com/test.html`, that simply means when a user clicks a link to `http://subdomainA.mywebsite.com/test.html`, it won't launch the APP? But my problem is, if the user visits `http://subdomainA.mywebsite.com/test.html` in browser, and click the link that links to `http://www.mywebsite.com/`, the App will be launched. But i don't want that happen. 

what i want to achieve is, if it is in `subdomainA.mywebsite.com`, if there is any link links to `http://www.mywebsite.com/`, it won't launch the APP. Is it possible to achieve that?